# How to close the current tab in magento 2 custom page?

Tags: magento2.3, jquery, custom-button

I have created one custom page .In this page one link is there ,while clicking the link I need to close the custom  page .how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it by adding JavaScript code ..

```
<script>
alert('we will close this window');
window.close();//this will close your window
</script>
```

**Solution 2:** with HTML also ..

```
<a href="javascript:close_window();">close</a>
```

in your close_window() function -

```
<script>
function close_window() {
  if (confirm("Close Window?")) {  //to confirm before closing is optional.
    close();
  }
}
</script>
```

**Edited Code**

```
<a href="javascript:window.close();">close</a>
```

Comment: it wasnt work it throws error in console "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them."

Comment: Try my edited code .. <a href="javascript:window.close();">close</a>

Comment: tried your edited code.still same error in console

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937212/window-close-doesnt-work-scripts-may-close-only-the-windows-that-were-opene